# Detect a pattern of keys entered in keyboard using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect my visitors to a page when they have pressed a secret code in the website, using keyboard. The keyboard code is "up up down down left right left right". I have written the code. But its not fully working. Because it only checks whether up, down, left and right arrow keys are pressed. Not the specific pattern. Below is the code

```
var map = {38: false, 38: false, 40: false, 40: false, 37: false, 39: false, 37: false, 39: false};
        $(document).keyup(function(e) 
        {
            if (e.keyCode in map) {
                map[e.keyCode] = true;
                if (map[38] && map[38] && map[40] && map[40] && map[37] && map[39] && map[37] && map[39]) {
                    alert('You have pressed the patten up up down downn left right left right')
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stargijo/7s401Lbp/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var key = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39],
    pos = 0;
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode !== key[pos]) {
        pos = 0;
    } else {
        ++pos;
        if (pos >= key.length) {
            pos = 0;
            alert('You have pressed the patten up up down downn left right left right');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro, you are getting this type of output because you are adding same Key and Value Pair in "Map", you had provided "38:false,38:false" this means same key and value provided two times, but only one key value can provided of one type. This means only four Key Value pair are existing and not 8 that's why it allows the user after single up-down-left-right.

Comment: Can you pls fix that for me?

Comment: Also, the order is not preserved in a map

Comment: wait for few min, i am trying Bro